# Create SQL Function for calculated column

Tags: sql, function

I am new to creating SQL functions from scratch. Basically I want to create a SQL function that will return this calculated column of a select statement

--edit--
I think my first example was oversimplified, I am hoping to call other functions and use OUTER APPLY in this new function (not sure if possible..).  Here is the actual code where I am trying to turn the select statement for this column into a function

```
Select 
s.[dbname] + '_' +[Tag2]
    + CASE WHEN [Tag3]='' 
            or tableA.[ignoreTag] is not null
            or isnumeric([Tag3])=1 
            or len([Tag3])=1 
            or isnumeric(left([Tag3],1))=1
        THEN ''
        ELSE '_'+[SomeDB].dbo.[RemoveNumericCharacters] ([tag3])
        END
    + CASE WHEN [tag4]='' 
            or tableB.[ignoreTag] is not null
            or isnumeric([tag4])=1 
            or len([tag4])=1 
            or isnumeric(left([Tag4],1))=1
        THEN ''
        ELSE '_'+[SomeDB].dbo.[RemoveNumericCharacters] ([tag4])
        END    as [Lookup]


FROM [SomeDB].[dbo].[mainTable] s 

outer apply (
    Select Top 1 * From [SomeDB].dbo.[LookupUseIgnoreTags] tableA
    Where s.[tag3] = tableA.[ignoretag]
    ) tableA

outer apply (
    Select Top 1 * From [SomeDB].dbo.[LookupUseIgnoreTags] tableB
    Where s.[tag4] = tableB.[ignoretag]
    ) tableB
```

---

to be used like...

```
Select
    [item1]
   ,[item2]
   ,[someDB].[dbo].[CalcColumnFunction]
FROM [someDB].dbo.[maintable]
```

--edit--

the function would contain a lot more case and joins (above is just the general idea), and i want it to be variable.  Currently i am using the CASE block in about 20 queries but it changes from time to time.. so i want to be able to simply update the function as needed instead of every query

Comment: Why do you want to create a function? Just use the `CASE` statement you have in the `Select` statement.

Comment: Then pass in ITEM to your function and return your desired value. What version of SQL?  MySQL? SQL SERVER? ORACLE?   But why?  I can see maybe code-reuse.. but seems like overkill unless you expect this to be used allover and changed alot.  Lots of online tutorials on creating functions with examples...  What have you tried? what's not working?

Comment: basically, the function would contain a lot more case and joins, and i want it to be variable.  Currently i am using the CASE block in about 20 queries but it changes from time to time.. so i want to be able to simply update the function as needed instead of every query

Answer (score 1):

Below function is just a example and it is returning 1 value.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.createfunction
(@Item VARCHAR(100))
RETURNS VARCHAR(100)
AS
BEGIN
   DECLARE @ItemValue VARCHAR(500) = NULL;    
   SET @ItemValue =  CASE  WHEN @Item='something' or @Item is not null THEN 'result1'  
                              WHEN @Item IN ('a','b') THEN 'result2'
                        ELSE 'otherResult' END
   RETURN @ItemValue;
END
```

---

I think in your scenario, you better return whole Table with function. See [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms191165(v=sql.105)) - you can return a whole table with a function.

Comment: --edit-- I think my first example was oversimplified, I am hoping to call other functions and use OUTER APPLY in this new function (not sure if possible..). Here is the actual code where I am trying to turn the select statement for this column into a function-- see new code above